# Arduino Keypad: the following key does not respond

Tags: keypad

I was wondering, by the time I press the following key, it does not return to the main_screen() function. How can I fix my code?

```
void loop()
  { 
    int exit = 0;
    char input = customKeypad.getKey();
    
    main_screen();
     if (input=='A')
        { 
          delay(100);
          lcd.clear();
         
          do{
   
           lcd.setCursor(1,0);
           lcd.print("Enter minutes: ");
   
   
             if (input=='B')
               {
                break;
                lcd.clear();
               }
           }
           while(1);
       }
```

}

Comment: can you also share the complete code?

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the input again after you get `input == 'A'`.  At the moment, when you enter the `do ... while` loop, the input is always 'A', so `input == 'B'` is never true, and the loop never exits.